# ADF Test Variation between tseries::adf.test in R and Matlab adftest

Tags: r, matlab, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm having an issue getting the p-values out of the ADF Test to match between the tseries package in R and the output in Matlab.

Using the example from the Matlab help located in the help [files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/adftest.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#examples)

```
>>load Data_GDP
>> Y=log(Data)
>> [h,hp, hs] = adftest(Y,'model','TS','lags',0:2)
h =
 0     0     0
hp =
0.6058    0.1841    0.0871
hs =
-1.9708   -2.8428   -3.2012
```

Compared to the values that are produced from the tseries function using the exact same data.

```
> tseries::adf.test(Y,k=0)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  Y
Dickey-Fuller = -1.971, Lag order = 0, p-value = 0.5881
alternative hypothesis: stationary

> tseries::adf.test(Y,k=1)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  Y
Dickey-Fuller = -2.8421, Lag order = 1, p-value = 0.222
alternative hypothesis: stationary

> tseries::adf.test(Y,k=2)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  Y
Dickey-Fuller = -3.2005, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.08863
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Any insight into why this is occurring would be very helpful. 
*EDIT* Added the test statistics, there are only small variances, could I consider the results equivalent?

Comment: Do the test regressions match? Do both have no intercept or an intercept, or an intercept and a trend?

Comment: My guess would be that the underlying tabulated critical values are different. From `?adf.test`: "The p-values are interpolated from Table 4.2, p. 103 of Banerjee et al. (1993)." From http://de.mathworks.com/help/econ/adftest.html#bta7rpp : "Critical values for a range of sample sizes and significance levels have been tabulated using Monte Carlo simulations of the null model with Gaussian innovations, with five million replications per sample size." Comparing the test statistics computed by MATLAB with those from R might help to confirm this.